# cudnn error while running a pyorch code on gpu

Tags: pytorch

I have the following error:
Traceback (most recent call last):

```
  File "odenet_mnist.py", line 343, in <module>
    logits = model(x)
  File "/home/subhashnerella/.conda/envs/pytorch/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 489, in __call__
    result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)
  File "/home/subhashnerella/.conda/envs/pytorch/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/container.py", line 92, in forward
    input = module(input)
  File "/home/subhashnerella/.conda/envs/pytorch/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 489, in __call__
    result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)
  File "/home/subhashnerella/.conda/envs/pytorch/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/conv.py", line 320, in forward
    self.padding, self.dilation, self.groups)
RuntimeError: cuDNN error: CUDNN_STATUS_EXECUTION_FAILED
```

This is not my code. I am just trying to run the code of a recent paper "Neural Ordinary Differential Equations"-by Chen et al.
Here is the link to the [code](https://github.com/rtqichen/torchdiffeq/blob/master/examples/odenet_mnist.py).

gpu: nvidia 2080Ti

pytorch version:'1.0.1.post2'

cuda 9.0

python 3.7.2

cudnn:

```
#define CUDNN_MAJOR 7
#define CUDNN_MINOR 4
#define CUDNN_PATCHLEVEL 2
--
#define CUDNN_VERSION (CUDNN_MAJOR * 1000 + CUDNN_MINOR * 100 + CUDNN_PATCHLEVEL)
```

I am new to pytorch. Why am i getting this error and how do i fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RTX2080Ti needs CUDA10 to work properly.Install the PyTorch binaries containing CUDA10

Comment: How do you figure out the minimum cuda version required for a GPU?